# Shift + F10 in TextBox KeyDown event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a text box.

```
myTB.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.myTB_KeyDown);
```

In this event I can get Keys.Apps to open the context menu.

Now another shortcut for context menu is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Is it possible to capture that too inside the `KeyDown` event?

Any logic that I can implement to capture those keys?

So far what I see is, when the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed, that time itself the `KeyDown` event get's called and no way checking for both <kbd>Shift</kbd> and  <kbd>F10</kbd> together!

Comment: see this link for documentation on how to do it they provide a similar example https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320584#bookmark-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, and you want to disable default <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> menu and handle those combination yourself, it's enough to handle [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event and detect the combination and the set `e.Handled=true;`:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode==  Keys.F10 && e.Shift==true)
    {
        //Shift +  F10 pressed, do what you need.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

You can also disable the default context menu that will be shown, by setting [`ShortcutsEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your `TextBox` to `false`.

Comment: Just because I am interested, what does the `e.Handled = true` part do?

Comment: Setting `e.Handled=true` prevents the default behavior. If the event is not handled, it will be sent to the operating system for default processing.

Comment: You're Welcome:) Correct me if I didn't understand your question and you are looking for something else :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty safe way to check for shift + F10

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.F10 | Keys.Shift))
        {
            if (txtBox1.Focused)
            {
                txtBox1.Text = "Captured!";
                return true;
            }
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Description:
This will capture every keystroke.  From there is will check if the keystroke is Shift+F10, the single pipe acts like `&&`.  After that it does a simple check to see if the textbox you are planning on having the event happen is focuses, or active control.  If it fails either of those checks it sends the information of the keystrokes to `return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);` which will give normal functionality to the keystroke without any overridden checks or whatever you may want to do with the captured keystrokes.